# How can I fix my centering problem?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, subfloats

I want to centering the third image. Here is the code and results:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}{0.6\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, height=5 cm]{3_8_1_Under-and-Overexposure_Overexposure-Sample.jpg}
  \centering   
    \caption{A sample of Over-exposured Image}
  \label{fig:3_8_1}
  \centering
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.6\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, height=5cm]{3_8_2_Under-and-Overexposure_Underexposure-Sample.jpg}
  \centering  
  \caption{A sample of Under-exposured Image}
   \label{fig:3_8_2}
  \centering  
   \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.6\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, height=5cm]{3_8_3_Under-and-Overexposure_Correct-Exposure-Sample-960x640.jpg}
  \centering  
  \caption{A sample of Well-exposured Image}
   \label{fig:3_8_3}
  \centering 
     \end{subfigure}
   \caption*{Source: https://photographylife.com/underexposure-and-overexposure-in-photography/}
 \caption{Samples for Over-exposured, Under-exposured and Well-exposured Images}  
    \end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

In your code snippet I delete all `\centering`s inside `subfigure`s, add `\centering` on beginning of `figure` environment and insert empty line before last `subfigure`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}% <-- changed
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=5 cm]{3_8_1_Under-and-Overexposure_Overexposure-Sample}
    \caption{A sample of Over-exposured Image}
  \label{fig:3_8_1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=5cm]{3_8_2_Under-and-Overexposure_Underexposure-Sample}
  \caption{A sample of Under-exposured Image}
   \label{fig:3_8_2}
   \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=5cm]{3_8_3_Under-and-Overexposure_Correct-Exposure-Sample-960x640}
  \caption{A sample of Well-exposured Image}
   \label{fig:3_8_3}
     \end{subfigure}

\caption*{Source: https://photographylife.com/underexposure-and-overexposure-in-photography/}

\caption{Samples for Over-exposured, Under-exposured and Well-exposured Images}
    \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Edit:
for centering of captions and comment in `\caption*`, which I suggest to enclose in caption), you need to add `\captionsetup{justification=centering, font=small}` in preamble (if this had valid at all captions in document) or on the begining of `figure` environment valid only for this figure):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup{justification=centering, font=small}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}% <-- changed
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=5 cm]{3_8_1_Under-and-Overexposure_Overexposure-Sample}
    \caption{A sample of Over-exposured Image}
  \label{fig:3_8_1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=5cm]{3_8_2_Under-and-Overexposure_Underexposure-Sample}
  \caption{A sample of Under-exposured Image}
   \label{fig:3_8_2}
   \end{subfigure}

\medskip
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=5cm]{3_8_3_Under-and-Overexposure_Correct-Exposure-Sample-960x640}
  \caption{A sample of Well-exposured Image}
   \label{fig:3_8_3}
     \end{subfigure}

\caption*{}

\caption[Samples for Over-exposured, Under-exposured and Well-exposured Images]
        {Samples for Over-exposured, Under-exposured and Well-exposured Images.\\ Source: \url{https://photographylife.com/underexposure-and-overexposure-in-photography/}}
    \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

[image]